# timer_settime calling handler function in pthread on uClinux

Tags: c, multithreading, timer, uclinux

I've got the following function that gets called from a pthread_create. This function does some work, sets a timer, does some other work and then waits for the timer to expire before doing the loop again. However, on the first run of the timer, after it expires the program quits and I'm not totally sure why. It should never leave the infinite while loop. The main thread accesses nothing from this thread and vice versa (for now).

My guess is I might not have something setup correctly with the thread, or the timer is not calling the handler function correctly. Perhaps changing the IDLE global variable from the thread causes a problem.

I would like to call the handler without signals, hence the use of SIGEV_THREAD_ID. I'm using the SIGUSRx signals in the main thread anyway.  Any thoughts about what I've started here what could be wrong?

```
#ifndef sigev_notify_thread_id
#define sigev_notify_thread_id _sigev_un._tid
#endif

volatile sig_atomic_t IDLE = 0;
timer_t timer_id;
struct sigevent sev;

void handler() {
    printf("Timer expired.\n");
    IDLE = 0;
}

void *thread_worker() {
    struct itimerspec ts;

    /* setup the handler for timer event */
    memset (&sev, 0, sizeof(struct sigevent));
    sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD_ID;
    sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = NULL;
    sev.sigev_notify_function = handler;
    sev.sigev_notify_attributes = NULL;
    sev.sigev_signo = SIGRTMIN + 1;
    sev.sigev_notify_thread_id = syscall(SYS_gettid);

    /* setup "idle" timer */
    ts.it_value.tv_sec = 55;
    ts.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
    ts.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    ts.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

    if (timer_create(0, &sev, &timer_id) == -1) {
        printf("timer_create failed: %d: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(3);
    }

    while (1) {
        // do work here before timer gets started that takes 5 seconds

        while (IDLE);   /* wait here until timer_id expires */

        /* setup timer */
        if (timer_settime(timer_id, 0, &ts, NULL) == -1) {
            printf("timer_settime failed: %d\n", errno);
            exit(3);
        }

        IDLE = 1;

        // do work here while timer is running but that does not take 10 seconds
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you haven't installed a signal handler for `SIGUSR1`, so by the default action it kills the process when it's acted upon.

In any case, the whole thing strikes me as extraordinarily bad design:

1. The while loop will give you 100% cpu load while waiting for the timer to expire.
2. This is not the way you use `SIGEV_THREAD_ID`, and in fact `SIGEV_THREAD_ID` isn't really setup to be usable by applications. Rather it's for the libc to use internally for implementing `SIGEV_THREAD`.
3. You really don't want to be using signals. They're messy.

If you have threads, why aren't you just calling `clock_nanosleep` in a loop? Timers are mainly useful when you can't do this, e.g. when you can't use threads.

Comment: I wasn't handling SIGUSR1 with this thread because I'm using it in the main thread. I agree I don't want to use signals with this. The whole function is not complete and I understand that the while loop is more/less just a busy loop hogging CPU. I wouldn't keep that there. I did not know that SIGEV_THREAD_ID was not setup for this type of work. I wish the documentation was more clear on that. If it is, I must have misunderstood. I wanted to use a timer and not a sleep function because there is some work to be done between when the timer is started to when it expires. Thanks for the feedback.